# YouTube player full screen issue

Tags: android

I was trying to implement YouTubePlayerView in View Pager whose parent view have a fixed height. When i click full screen/exit mode in YouTube player it's adjusting only with respect to view pager's parent height, which i guess is an obvious behavior.

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp">
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/productImageSlider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
            <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Now, as new in android, i want to know, if re-parenting the ViewPager on entering full screen mode is a good option to make it work or do i have other choices?

Comment: **re-parenting** what do you mean by that? if you want full height , I would suggest just change the height of parent at run time

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to set your views to match parent when you want to go fullscreen.

```
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(
    new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

If when you exit fullscreen you want to go back the previous height and width, store the values somewhere and set them in the same way when the app exits fullscreen.